# Detecting utf8mb4 characters in python

Tags: python, mysql

Is there a way to detect characters in a python string which require utf8mb4 encoding to store in a mysql/mariadb database?

Comment: Why do you think you need to detect such characters? **All** of Unicode can be stored with that codec.

Comment: Closed before I could answer... utf8mb4 character ranges all start with 11110xxx as the first byte, so you could use:  "any(ord(c)>=240 for c in value)".  If True, then it requires utf8mb4.  If False, then it fits in 1-3 bytes.